# How do I reset the count when a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reset the count to 0 when conditions 1 or 2 are met  when looping through one function every 2 seconds. At what point would I implement the reset. For example;

```
var timer;
var a = 'door';
var b = '';//this is set by an ajax call that fires off every second

var count = 0;

function condition(){
    //condition 1
    if(a == 'door' && b == 'inside' && count < 30){
        $('#action').html('Person A');
        count++;
    //after 1 minute show 1 minute sign
    } else {
        $('#action').html('It\'s been 1 minute');
        count = 31;
    }
    //condition 2
    if(a == 'door' && b == 'outside' && count < 30){
        $('#action').html('Person B');
        count++;
    //after 1 minute show 1 minute sign
    } else {
        $('#action').html('It\'s been 1 minute');
        count = 31;
    }
    //condition 3
    //empty div & reset count
    if(b == ''){
        $('#action').empty();
        count = 0;
    }
    //set interval
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(condition, 2000);// 2 seconds x 30 = 1 minute
}
condition();
```

Comment: What is working? What isn't working? How often is the ajax call fired, and is it ensured that it will always return outside or inside? There are a lot of potential issues and solutions.

Comment: Currently as it is now, the action id is being emptied and the count is set to 0. I would like it to start the count all over again after 30 iterations or when it meets a different condition. The ajax is called every second.

Answer (score 0):

There's something off with your code, specifically for the `setInterval` function. The first parameter should be a function object, **NOT** the invokation of a function:

Should be this:

```
setInterval( condition, 2000 );
```